# How do we know that dark matter energy density scales as $\rho\propto a^{-3}$?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-matter, density

How do we know that dark matter energy density scales as  $\rho\propto a^{-3}$?

Comment: It is just an hypothesis.  The simplest one.  It is possible that DM interact with itself, so the DM pressure isn't necessarily 0 : $p \ne 0$ and $\rho_{\mathrm{DM}}$ may be more complicated than simple pressureless matter.  Currently, it is the simplest *model* of "cold" DM.  Some guys are postulating a global *scalar field* (which have pressure even if it isn't interacting with itself!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expansion of the universe is described by a solution to Einstein's equation called the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) and two related equations called the [Friedmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations). In these we have an energy density that is normally divided into three parts:

1. relativistic matter and radiation
2. non-relativistic matter
3. dark energy/cosmological constant

For more on this see my answer to [Is Dark Matter called "Matter" only because of gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293364/is-dark-matter-called-matter-only-because-of-gravity)

The three parts scale as $a^{-4}$, $a^{-3}$ and $a^0$ (i.e. constant) respectively. The densities of these three components were [measured by the Planck experiment](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209) and found to be:

$$ \begin{align}
\Omega_{R,0} &= 9.24\times 10^{-5},\\
\Omega_{M,0} &= 0.315,\\
\Omega_{\Lambda,0} &= 0.685,
\end{align}$$

So we know that just under a third of the *stuff* in the universe scales in the way we expect non-relativistic matter to scale, and we therefore assume that it is indeed non-relativistic matter. However visible matter makes up only about 4-5% of the matter/energy in the universe, so we are left with 26% or so of *stuff* that is measured by Planck to scale in the same way as non-relativistic matter but that we cannot see. This is what we call dark matter.

So the answer to your question:

> How do we know that dark matter energy density scales as  $\rho\propto a^{-3}$?

is simply that the Planck measurements tell us that there is around 26% of the *stuff* in the universe that scales as $a^{-3}$ but that we can't see. And for want of a better name this we have called dark matter.

So it isn't that we have determined that dark matter scales as $a^{-3}$, but rather that we have observed something scaling as $a^{-3}$ and called it *dark matter*.

Comment: With all due respect @John Rennie, is this really correct? Planck measures the densities at a point in time and thus can not make a statement about the scaling relation. The difference between baryons and dark matter for Planck is only whether the density BAO oscillates or not, isnt it.

Answer (score 3):

Dark matter is assumed to be similar to ordinary matter, but without electromagnetic interactions. (The density of ordinary non-relativistic matter scales as the inverse cube of the scale factor, so non-relativistic or “cold” dark matter is assumed to as well.) This assumption seems to be validated by the observational success of the standard model of cosmology, called Lambda-Cold-Dark-Matter, particularly regarding the details of the cosmic microwave background.

So we “know” this in the same way that we “know” many things in physics: it is one part of an accepted and successful theory that makes other predictions which are observed. That leads us to have reasonable confidence that it is true.

Comment: _"so non-relativistic or “cold” dark matter is assumed to as well."_  At high enough temperatures, everything should be relativistic including dark matter! Right? Is this therefore incorrect to infer that dark matter should not always have scaled like $\sim a^{-3}$? @G.Smith

Comment: When they were highly relativistic in the early universe, both ordinary matter and dark matter scaled like radiation did, as the inverse fourth power.

Comment: So is this scaling feature is valid after DM became nonrelativistic? @G.Smith

Comment: The transition to this scaling occurred as *both* regular matter and dark matter became non-relativistic.