# Does the information paradox exist without second quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, quantum-information, second-quantization, unitarity

### Background

So according to Greiner's Book - Relativistic Quantum Mechanics one can perfectly proceed without second quantization of the Dirac Equation. The gist of which is captured in Chapter $12$:

> Let us stress the point that the hole theory is a many-body theory,
> describing particles with positive and negative charge. Indeed,
> infinitely many electrons are needed to constitute the Dirac sea. The
> simple probability interpretation of the wave functions acclaimed in a
> single-particle theory cannot be true any longer, because the creation
> and annihilation of electron—positron pairs must be taken into account
> in the wave functions.

I've also seen [examples](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/121890/150174) of first quantized gravity as well (I'm suggesting one goes into a non-inertial frame as shown in the example)

### Question

This begs the question: does a version of Hawking's [information paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox) without second quantization exist? (A counter proof why it can't exist will suffice as well)

Comment: Note that one can consider interacting many-body systems without resorting to second quantization. It may be not common in QFT, but rather commonplace in solid state physics.